# Google Sign In Failed (ApiException: 12501)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games

I'm trying to sign in with Google Play Games. This is the code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .build();

googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

I launch the GoogleSignInActivity with this code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
        }
    });
```

And then, it returns back here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }
}
```

So at this line:

```
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
```

I get this error:

```
Google sign in failed: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501
```

There isn't any error with the SHA1 certificate because I have generated it many times and pasted it in the Firebase Console, also I have this permissions at the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Any piece of my code is deprecated. I am using the latest dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
```

I have read all the possible documentation. I am so desperate with this, almost one week with this problem...

Comment: Try checking this [Firebase AuthDemo](https://github.com/mahdit83/FireBaseAuthDemo): first enable Google Sign-in in Firebase Console, second you should created SHA1 debug key and add to Firebase console (which you have already done), third create  android OAuth 2.0 client ID and lastly get generated google-service.json from Firebase console and put in app folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. The problem is that I am not sign in with Google, I am sign in with Google Play Games. So I created the OAuth 2.0 Android Client ID and generated again the google-service.json file. Then I enabled the Play Games Sign-in in Firebase Console and I created an OAuth 2.0 Web Client ID with the secret client bla bla bla... I generated again the google-services.json file and put in app folder and then I get that error `Google sign in failed: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501`

Comment: weird, then have you linked your Firebase project to your play publisher account and whitelist the email you are using?

Comment: yes, I have. It seems I have all that I need. however, the error persists...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN
```

to

```
GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN
```

Comment: Please provide more descriptive context of you answer to help understand the difference